# How to perform Mongodb CDC using wso2 streaming integrator?

Tags: wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm so confused I don't know how to perform mongo cdc with wso2 streaming integrator. I set up a mongo replicaset follow this [doc](https://github.com/isayme/mongo-replica-compose). I config cdc source like below,
[image]
but it doesn't work, I got these error logs . Can any one help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an issue with the extension installer script of the WSO2 SI. The mongo_java_driver is actually a bundled jar and due to that it should not be converted again into a bundle.

So to fix your problem, Follow the below steps,

**Step 1**- Uninstall the installed MongoDB jar.
**Step 2**- Go to WSO2SI_HOME/wso2/server/resources/extensionsInstaller folder and open the extensionDependencies.json file.
**Step 3**- Search for  **"name": "mongo-java-driver"** and under the configurations usage type from "JAR" to "BUNDLE".
**Step 4**- reinstall the MongoDB extension via extension installer

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I doesn't work, but works when replacing mongo-java-driver 3.4.2.jar to 3.12.7.jar

Answer (score 0):

Have you copy the mongo-java-driver to <PRODUCT_HOME>/lib directory? it seems like the cdc extension couldn't locate the mongodb drivers

Comment: Yes, I did. I installed cdc-mongo extension from ui, the mongo-java-driver was bean downloaded by app with name "mongo_java_driver_3.4.2_1.0.0.jar" in <tooling-home>lib and "mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar" located in <tooling-home>/.jars , I don't know what's different between them. I restart app and create an siddhi-app but failed to start like above. Did i miss something? Or I need to copy mongi-java-driver3.4.2 from .jars to lib ?

Comment: I am using wso2si-tooling-4.2.0-alpha, I' m confused it says com.mongodb.mongoclientsettings not found in siddhi-io-cdc_2.0.13, for siddhi-io-cdc use debe-mongodb-connetor which depency is mongodb-driver-sync not mongodb-driver-java.